# How to remove all child items of the root item in tree view

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to remove all the tree items in the tree view of the invisible Root Item.

Currently this is what my workflow is

```
QModelIndex index = treeView->rootIndex();
QAbstractItemModel *model = treeView->model();
TreeModel *myModel = qobject_cast<TreeModel*>(model);
TreeItem* itm = myModel->getItem(index);
itm->removeChildren(0, itm->childCount());


  bool TreeItem::removeChildren(int position, int count)
{
    if (position < 0 || position > childItems.count())
        return false;

    for (int row = 0; row < count; ++row)
    {
        delete childItems.takeAt(position);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Though i am able to delete all the items in the tree view it seems as if the Tree model indexes are not getting updated.

After deleting all the Tree items if i try to add a new item the application crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You need delete your elements in between these calls.

```
beginResetModel();
```

and

```
endResetModel()
```